window.scrollTo causes issues with my Menu component (Material UI)
I will try to explain my issue as detailed as possible but please feel free to ask me if anything else is needed.
My web application frontend is built with React , I have my Home page component which looks like this:
import React, { useRef } from "react";
import Banner from "../../Banner/Banner";
import ProductCarousel from "../../productCarousel/productCarousel";

const Home = () => {
  const productCarouselRef = useRef(null);

  const scrollToCarousel = () => {
    window.scrollTo({
      top: productCarouselRef.current.offsetTop,
      behavior: "smooth",
    });
  };

  return (
    <div className="home-container">
      <Banner className="home-banner" onShopNowClick={scrollToCarousel} />
      <div ref={productCarouselRef}>
        <ProductCarousel />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Home;

so basically I have a banner component which accepts onClick function , in my usecase I send scrollToCarousel so when clicking on the banner button I should be scrolled down to my product carousel.
My product carousel consists 4 sliders each has an "add to cart" button , clicking this button should trigger a menu in order to choose a size. My issue is that when I press the add-to-cart button without using the banner button before to scroll down will open the menu in the correct place but if I would use the banner button to scroll down , if I will press the add-to-cart button the menu is being open in the wrong place on the page , I will share a picture how it looks as well as my
ProductCarousel compnent :
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import {
  CarouselProvider,
  Slider,
  Slide,
  ButtonBack,
  ButtonNext,
} from "pure-react-carousel";
import "pure-react-carousel/dist/react-carousel.es.css";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import "./productCarousel.css";
import { Button, Menu, MenuItem } from "@mui/material";
import { notification } from "antd";
import ArrowBackIosIcon from "@mui/icons-material/ArrowBackIos";
import ArrowForwardIosIcon from "@mui/icons-material/ArrowForwardIos";

const ProductCarousel = () => {
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);
  const [selectedSizes, setSelectedSizes] = useState({});
  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = useState(null);
  const [currentProduct, setCurrentProduct] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchProducts = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await axios.get("http://localhost:5000/api/products");
        setProducts(response.data);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error fetching products:", error);
      }
    };

    fetchProducts();
  }, []);

  const handleOpenMenu = (event, product) => {
    setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
    setCurrentProduct(product);
  };

  const handleCloseMenu = () => {
    setAnchorEl(null);
    setCurrentProduct(null);
  };

  const handleSizeSelect = async (size) => {
    const product = currentProduct;
    handleCloseMenu();

    try {
      await axios.post(
        "http://localhost:5000/api/cart/items",
        {
          productId: product._id,
          quantity: 1,
          size: size,
        },
        { withCredentials: true } // Ensure cookies are sent with the request
      );
      notification.success({
        message: "Added to Cart",
        description: `${product.name} (Size: ${size}) has been added to your cart.`,
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error adding to cart:", error);
      notification.error({
        message: "Failed to Add to Cart",
        description:
          "There was an error adding the product to your cart. Please try again.",
      });
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="product-carousel-container">
      <h2 className="producut-carousel-header">HOT ITEMS</h2>
      <CarouselProvider
        naturalSlideWidth={100}
        naturalSlideHeight={125}
        totalSlides={products.length}
        visibleSlides={4}
        infinite
        dragEnabled
      >
        <Slider>
          {products.map((product, index) => (
            <Slide index={index} key={product._id} className="product-item">
              <Link to={`/product/${product._id}`} className="product-link">
                <div className="product-content">
                  <div className="product-image-container">
                    <img
                      src={product.imageUrl}
                      alt={product.name}
                      className="product-image"
                    />
                  </div>
                  <div className="product-info">
                    <h3>{product.name}</h3>
                    <p>{product.description}</p>
                    <p>${product.price}</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </Link>
              {product.sizes.length > 0 && (
                <div className="product-actions">
                  <Button
                    variant="contained"
                    color="primary"
                    onClick={(event) => handleOpenMenu(event, product)}
                  >
                    Add to Cart
                  </Button>
                </div>
              )}
            </Slide>
          ))}
        </Slider>
        <ButtonBack className="carousel-button prev">
          <ArrowBackIosIcon fontSize="small" />
        </ButtonBack>
        <ButtonNext className="carousel-button next">
          <ArrowForwardIosIcon fontSize="small" />
        </ButtonNext>
      </CarouselProvider>

      <Menu
        anchorEl={anchorEl}
        open={Boolean(anchorEl)}
        onClose={handleCloseMenu}
      >
        {currentProduct &&
          currentProduct.sizes.map((size) => (
            <MenuItem key={size} onClick={() => handleSizeSelect(size)}>
              {size}
            </MenuItem>
          ))}
      </Menu>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ProductCarousel;

How it looks when clicking add-to-cart after using the banner button
How it looks when clicking add-t-cart without using the banner button
When trying to log my event.currentTarget I get
<button class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiButton-root MuiButton-contained MuiButton-containedPrimary MuiButton-sizeMedium MuiButton-containedSizeMedium MuiButton-colorPrimary MuiButton-root MuiButton-contained MuiButton-containedPrimary MuiButton-sizeMedium MuiButton-containedSizeMedium MuiButton-colorPrimary css-1lw0m7l-MuiButtonBase-root-MuiButton-root" tabindex="0" type="button">Add to Cart<span class="MuiTouchRipple-root css-8je8zh-MuiTouchRipple-root"></span></button> 

which I think should be the correct HTML element
